# Solution verification: no element of the ideal $(x^2, x^3)$ in the ring $k[x^2, x^3]$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

**Is the following proof that no element of $(x^2, x^3)$ in $k[x^2, x^3]$ is prime valid?**

I'm also curious whether I'm making a big assumption (like uniqueness of factorization) that is not safe to sweep under the rug.

---

I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637814) yesterday and the ring that the author mentioned is quite interesting.

$S$ is defined as $k[x^2, x^3]$ where $k$ is an arbitrary field.

I have never seen a ring like this before.

It is not hard to show that *every* monomial $x^n$ where $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$ is expressible as a sum of a finite number of $2$s and $3$s.

Because of this $S = k[x^2, x^3]$ consists of elements of $k[x]$ of the form $\sum a_ix^i $ where all but finitely many $a_i$ are zero and $a_1$ is constrained to be zero. Any monomial besides $x^1$ can be represented by combining $x^2$ and $x^3$ and we get $1 = x^0$ for free.

That question asks us to consider whether the ideal $(x^2, x^3)$ in $S$ and whether it contains any prime elements.

We can prove that the ideal $(x^2, x^3)$ is prime because the only elements *not* in the ideal are the nonzero elements of $k$, which are closed under multiplication.

I tried for a bit yesterday to prove that $(x^2, x^3)$ contains or does not contain a prime element, but then I hit a wall and gave up.

Earlier today, I looked at the element $x^2 + x^3$.

This element is not prime:

- $x^2 + x^3 \nmid (x^2 + x^3)x \;\;\text{because $x$ is not in $S$}$
- $x^2 + x^3 \nmid (x^2 + x^3)x$
- BUT $x^2 + x^3 \mid (x^2 + x^3)(x^2 + x^3)(x^2)$

This makes me wonder if the same strategy for witnessing the non-primality of an element always works for elements of $(x^2, x^3)$.

##### Theorem 101: No element of $(x^2, x^3)$ is prime.

An element of $(x^2, x^3)$ has the form $ax^2 + bx^3$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonzero polynomials in $k[x]$.

- $ax^2 + bx^3 \nmid (ax^2 + bx^3)x \;\; \text{because $x$ is not in $S$}$
- $ax^2 + bx^3 \nmid (ax^2 + bx^3)x$
- BUT $ax^2 + bx^3 \mid (ax^2 + bx^3)(ax^2 + bx^3)(x^2)$ because $(ax^2 + bx^3)(x^2)$ is in $S$.

Suppose the element is $0$, then we're done because zero is not prime.

Suppose the element has the form $ax^2$. Note that elements of the form $bx^3$ also have the form $(bx)x^2$.

- $ax^2 \nmid (ax^2)x$
- $ax^2 \nmid (ax^2)x$
- BUT $ax^2 \mid (ax^2)(ax^2)(x^2)$

This exhausts the possibilities.

*End of proof of Theorem 101*

Comment: You can extract $x^2$ from $ax^2+bx^3$, and see that an element of $(x^2,x^3)$ is actually always of the form $ax^2$, where $a$ again is an arbitrary polynomial of $k[x]$.

Comment: The proof seems fine to me, implicitly you are using the inclusion $k[x^2,x^3]\subseteq k[x]$ and in the latter we do have uniqueness of decomposition, so everything works nicely.